# An English equivalent for someone who is a "тормоз"

Tags: word-request

We have a word as **тормоз** (pronounced: **tormoz** mean **brake** in English) in Russian which is usually attributed to a very slowly working person whose slowness causes some malfunction in team-working and group activities and might bring about  an influence on their teammates performance.

The term can be utilized either humorously or sarcastically.

I am wondering if there is any English equivalent for that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several words or phrases that may suit your translation depending on the exact context. These include "dead weight", "millstone", "dead wood", "waste of space / air / oxygen", "not pulling their weight". There are undoubtedly others contributors can think of.

Comment: +1 for "dead weight".